# Volumetric / Atmosphere Cutoff Problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I am rendering a landscape scene with realistic scale values (about 6000 meters) in cycles.

I need a very fine atmospheric effect, but below a certain density value the volumetric shader abruptly cuts off and is gone (s. attachment) . I can not find a cutoff setting for volumetric effects in the render settings. (And I don't want to got for the mist pass etc.) Any help?[image: 2 different values with sudden dropoff]

Comment: I think the _Mist Pass_ is exactly for these things useful.

Comment: Well Gordon, but it is a completely different approach. Surely I can do a lot in postproduction or paint in some clouds by hand. But I am looking for reliable atmospherics that catch the ambient + direct light etc.

Comment: I know, this is why I write no answer. I suspect the problem with the falloff here has something to do with floating point accuracy but since I'm no developer I can't tell. For the falloff itself I don't find a setting (although in my scene it is below 0.0275 × 0.001 that it suddenly disappears) and I'm quite sure it has to do with the real world scale - because it is not the resulting visible density. If I use a landscape of 600 m instead of 6000 m, I can use higher density values and achieve less dense mist then what I get right before it disappears at a larger scale.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Apperantly there is no such setting yet. Thomas Kohle put it here - let's see if some developer finds it worthy: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/104504